# Решить систему линейных уравнений где неизвестных больше чем уравнений

Tags: c#, c++, c, алгоритм, математика

Помогите понять как решить данный пример, я понимаю что это линейное уравнение но такой вид не решается ни одной из тех библиотек которые я нашел:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В существующих библиотеках которые я использовал, насколько я понял неизвестных должно быть столько же сколько и уравнений, в моем примере неизвестных больше. Как найти подходящий алгоритм?
Я использовал алгоритмы взятые тут: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Linear-Systems-Solving-8562e8b8
Но я не все понял, например есть алгоритм EigenVVReal, который помимо основных входных (как например алгоритм

```
LUDecomposition(  int n,
            double[,] a,
            double[] b,
            double[] x)
    //кол-во уравнений, матрица1, матрица2(то что после =), результат
```

принимает еще не понятные мне массивы:

```
public int reaeig3(double[,] a, int n, double[] em, double[] val, double[,] vec)
```

Если подскажите библиотеку, которая сможет решить или как пользоваться уже имеющимися, буду благодарен.
Для удобства, залил все алгоритмы на гитхаб: https://github.com/milovidov983/LinearSystems

Comment: Решая переопределённые системы, получают не одиночное решение. Обычно задача - найти оптимальное по некоему критерию решение. А порой - область определения системы. В общем, абстрактно такие системы не решают.

Comment: @Akina да вы правы у меня есть еще одно условие но что бы не усложнять вопрос я не стал его приводить. Условие в том что для x1 и x2 существуют известные значение A1 для x1 и A2 для x2 которые x1 и x2 не должны превышать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приведённый пример - [линейное Диофантово уравнение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) с двумя неизвестными типа

```
A * x + B * y = C
```

Пример реализации решения для разных условий на [e-maxx](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/export_diofant_2_equation)

Код для случая одного произвольного решения:

```
bool find_any_solution (int a, int b, int c, int & x0, int & y0, int & g) {
    g = gcd (abs(a), abs(b), x0, y0);
    if (c % g != 0)
        return false;
    x0 *= c / g;
    y0 *= c / g;
    if (a < 0)   x0 *= -1;
    if (b < 0)   y0 *= -1;
    return true;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваше время, скажите как быть если к тому что уже есть прибавить условие что для x1 и x2 существуют известные значение A1 для x1 и A2 для x2 которые x1 и x2 не должны превышать?

Comment: И еще один вопрос, пока я в теме до конца не разобрался. Скажите если уравнение будет больше например 1x+2y+3z....99zz =1234567 то алгоритм будет уже другой?

Comment: По первому вопросу - приведённая ссылка как раз содержит раздел "Нахождение количества решений и сами решения в заданном отрезке"

Comment: Второй вопрос - надо понять реальную задачу. Вдруг это задача о наборе суммы из заданного набора монет

Comment: Да это подбор количества монет если можно так сказать, x это цена A это количество.

Comment: Подозреваю, что наборот - цена A известна, x[i] - неизвестное количество.. Если количество может быть дробным, например, с точностью до грамма, то можно задачу свести к целочисленной умножением на 1000 и решать динамическим программированием.

Comment: Не совсем так, известно количество и общая сумма C а цена не известна, нужно произвести подбор цен по всем позициям и учесть условие x <= A1, где A1 известное число, и да все числа положительные.

Comment: ОК, тогда цена в копейках и множитель 100.

Comment: Добавлю ещё до кучи - если есть некие критерии **оптимизации** решения, то посмотрите также  в сторону задачи линейного программирования

Comment: Диофантово уравнение - это когда надо решать в целых или рациональных числах.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Именно так и есть в приведённом примере

Comment: @MBo не вижу требования рациональности в вопросе

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Автор - партизан, подробности приходится выпытывать. А в его новом вопросе есть и упоминание, что все числа целые, и формулировка без чёткого указания на целочисленность коэфф.